# WPF C#: How to add a usercontrol to a thumb control programatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, slider

another day, another question :) :
At the moment in my XAML i have a thumb on a canvas which contains a usercontrol:

```
<Canvas Name="SweetCanvas">
  <Thumb Name="tmbThumb"  Canvas.Left="245" Canvas.Top="185" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta">
     <Thumb.Template>
       <ControlTemplate>
         <my:UserControl1 />
       </ControlTemplate>
      </Thumb.Template>
   </Thumb>
</Canvas>
```

which works. But i want to add a thumb like this programatically, so i tried this:

```
UserControl1 newUC= new UserControl1 (); //UserControl i want on the thumb
Thumb tmbDragThumb = new Thumb()
tmbDragThumb.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(Thumb_DragDelta); //event for the thumb
//Dont really know what to do here :/
tmbDragThumb.Template = newUC; //Adding usercontrol to something something something?

SweetCanvas.Children.Add(tmbDragThumb); //add the final Thumb to Canvas
```

I don't really know how to add content to this thumb, like i did in the XAML

Comment: I guess you have to create a template first, just like in xaml

Comment: But how does this work? :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just found a solution by myself using the FrameworkElementFactory:

```
Thumb tmbDragThumb = new Thumb();
tmbDragThumb.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(Thumb_DragDelta);
ControlTemplate template = new ControlTemplate();
var fec= new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(UserControl1 ));
template.VisualTree = fec;
tmbDragThumb.Template = template;

SweetCanvas.Children.Add(tmbDragThumb);
```

this was helpful: 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WPF-Styles-and-Control-b6732c24